# UK Tier 2 visa - NARIC

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, language-test

do we get an email of the NARIC letter form NARIC UK which can be uploaded for Visa documents or do we have to wait for the letter to arrive on mail?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to the NARIC FAQs https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/Individuals/FAQs.aspx assessments are provided by mail.  Receipt by email is not listed under ‘Delivery options’ https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/Individuals/Postage%20Options.aspx